# OpenVidu Publisher Sound from Ear Speaker

Tags: ios, iphone, ionic-framework, speaker, openvidu

I use openvidu in my app. When I subscribe to a publisher video, publisher's sound comes out from the earpiece (like during a call). How can I set output source to speaker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by doing the following in Ionic 4+.

**1. You need to use the following plugin**

https://github.com/neohelden/cordova-plugin-audiotoggle

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/neohelden/cordova-plugin-audiotoggle
```

**2. In your component.ts where you want to enable the ear-piece or speaker**

```
declare var AudioToggle: any;

//Method To Enable Earpiece

enableEarpiece(){
     if(this.platform.is('cordova')){
          AudioToggle.setAudioMode(AudioToggle.EARPIECE);
     }
}

// Method To Enable the Speakers

enableSpeaker(){
     if(this.platform.is('cordova')){
          AudioToggle.setAudioMode(AudioToggle.SPEAKER);
     }
}
```